# cy.origin error when interacting element on secondary domain

Tags: cypress

I've been encountering this issue for a long time and not sure what I need to do to make it work:
[image]

[image]

I am using Cypress version 12.17.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with the `www` part of the URL specified.

```js
cy.origin('https://www.mailinator.com', {args: setArgs}, ({patientEmail}) => {
  ...
})
```

Cypress is very fussy about domain matching the actual page location to the specified domain (i.e the first parameter to `cy.origin()`).

It can fail with the smallest discrepancy - frequently it fails on `http:` vs `https:`.